# Hiding status bar IOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to hide the status bar, or at least change the color of the icons to white because they don't fit with my design. I have tried to put "none" and "lighten" from storyboard, and by using this code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

}
```

...and setting hide status bar at app launch, but the status bar is still, stuck there. There was no way to change the color of the icons either. Why?

Comment: Please explain before down voting my question

Comment: Sorry, wrong code, my mistake

Comment: You are using an outdated method and this question has been asked a lot - you should check the search function before posting and that is the reason for my down-vote.

Comment: oh I get it, it didn't work because I am running iOS 7 and from what I have understood the method has changed with the iOS update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to hide statusbar throughout app is just 
go into your **Info.plist**; right click to add a row and select **Status Bar Initially hidden**.

This will ensure every time you app launches the status bar will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Targets => Summary and there you should check "Hide during application launch" and it will solve your problem

[image]