# How do I get rid of the status bar all together in Xcode 5.

Tags: iphone, xcode, statusbar

How do I get rid of the status bar, using Xcode 5 and developing for the iPhone. I need to get the status bar out of my app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding status bar IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834318/hiding-status-bar-ios)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide a status bar in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661031/how-to-hide-a-status-bar-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

In your Info.plist file set:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```